# Does it make sense to throw a private exception?

Tags: java, exception, visibility, runtime-error, invariants

I want to throw a runtime exception in case my class invariants are invalidated. Since this is a programming error (similar to a NullPointerException), clients should not catch that exception.

Should the exception class be declared private or public (or something else)?

```
class Foo
{
    // ...

    private static class InvariantsViolated
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Are there any guidelines on custom runtime exceptions and visibility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider using an existing exception unless you expect this exception to be caught in a different way. If it is not expected to be caught, I don't see the need for a custom exception.  Some exceptions you could re-use

- [AssertionError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) - To me this means there is an unrecoverable programming error of an indeterminate type.
- [IllegalArgumentException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) - To me this means only of the arguments to the method was invalid.
- [IllegalStateException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) - To me this means the state of the object (e.g. combination of values) is not valid for this operation.

If you want a custom exception you may consider extending these exceptions, or using one of the exceptions which extend these.

Comment: I would not throw AssertionError by hand, but using assertions to check invariants is a good thing.

Comment: `assert` needs to be turned on to function. You may want this check to occur all the time.

Comment: In fact, I had considered `IllegalStateException`, but its documentation says "Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time." which is not the case.

Comment: Have a look at IllegalBlockingModeException, IllegalComponentStateException, InvalidMarkException which all extend IllegalStateException. These indicate the object is in an illegal state to be used.  IMHO This could include a `validate()` method

Comment: But I do not want do indicate an "illegal state to be used", I want to indicate a *programming error* inside `Foo`.

Comment: I would suggest an AssertionError is approriate for programming errors.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in order to `throw` anything, that object has to implement the `Throwable` interface, which meant that it has to be either an `Error` or an `Exception`. Since you don't want your clients to catch that event *ever*, you should probably use an `Error`. From the [`Error` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html):

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable
>   that indicates serious problems that a
>   reasonable application should not try
>   to catch.

That way you *may* avoid the dreaded `Exception` catch-alls some programmers tend to use - most times these programmers don't even think about catching an `Error` at all...

Comment: That's why we use `Throwable` catch-alls in our app ;-)